# Can we use ATTiny 85 for boot loading

Tags: avr

Atmega8 can be used for boot loading another chip by making USBASP programmer using Atmega8. Can we make USBASP programer using ATTINY85 chip? I guess flash is not a constraint. Any other constaraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you took a look at the data sheet?

The attiny85 only has 8 Pins. No place for a Crystal for correct USB communication timings. It also has no SPI but a very limited USI interface.

Buying the right controller would be much easier than redevelopping USBASP hard/firmware to use an tiny85

Comment: The firmware changes required are actually not all that extensive, and the ATtiny85 does have *just* enough I/O. But I would also recommend a larger chip.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it only has 6 Pins if you disable the reset pin. so there are your 4 ISP interface and 2 for the USB communication. You cannot use a Crystal that may be a big Problem for the Software USB-Stack and as far as i remember the Software-USB-Implementation uses 3 Pins because it doubles one of them additionally to a Int0 or Int 1 (but iam not sure about this)

Comment: You only need a third pin if one of your other two pins isn't an interrupt pin. And the RC oscillator can be calibrated to be accurate enough for low-speed USB. D- connects to PB2, D+ connects to PB3, the clock is triggered via timer 0 and output on PB4, and PB5 holds the target in reset.